# How to get how many messages has been sent in a channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the number of how many messages have been sent in a channel, and using the logs_from() function wont work because that only accepts a fixed amount of messages to retrieve, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite) branch, there is a [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) `AsyncIterator`.  If you pass `limit=None`, it will return all the messages from the channel

```
@bot.command()
async def message_count(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    count = 0
    async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
        count += 1
    await ctx.send("There were {} messages in {}".format(count, channel.mention))
```

You might try passing `limit=None` to `logs_from`, but it isn't documented as working that way like it is in the rewrite branch.