# Discord.py server stats command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command that will show most useful server stats. I tried to make something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def serverstats(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Statystyki serwera {ctx.guild.name}")
    embed.add_field(name="Users:", value=ctx.guild.members, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Channels:", value=ctx.guild.channels, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Messages sent:", value=???, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But i don't know how can i make messages counter, and other counters return not correct or strange data

Comment: Iterate over all your channels and [count the number of messages in each channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223394/3994202).

Comment: Yeah, but how can i do this?

Comment: I would start with `for channel in ctx.guild.channels: print(channel)`. And next I would try to use object `channels` to count messages in this channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the users and channel counter, you would use the `len()` function to count how many there are. If you don't have the members [intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) enabled, you can also use `ctx.guild.member_count`.

```py
# Using len()...
embed.add_field(name="Users:", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Channels:", value=len(ctx.guild.channels), inline=False)
```

For messages however, you will need to use a database or global variable and manually increase the entry each time a message is sent. A global variable is much simpler to use than a database, however it will be flushed whenever the script ends or is restarted.

*On a side note, if you want to use a database anyway, I recommend you check out [dataset](https://github.com/pudo/dataset).*

```py
# Using a global variable (dictionary)

# Somewhere in your code...
messagecounts = {}

...

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild.id not in messagecounts.keys(): # Make sure there's already an entry... If not, add one!
        messagecounts[message.guild.id] = 0
    messagecounts[message.guild.id] += 1 # Sets the new count to 1 greater than the original.
```

Then, to retrieve this amount, you would add the dictionary entry.
Final Code:

```py
# Somewhere above the command...
messagecounts = {}

@bot.command()
async def serverstats(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Statystyki serwera {ctx.guild.name}")
    embed.add_field(name="Users:", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Channels:", value=len(ctx.guild.channels), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Messages sent:", value=messagecounts[ctx.guild.id], inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild.id not in messagecounts.keys():
        messagecounts[message.guild.id] = 0
    messagecounts[message.guild.id] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For users, you can try using `ctx.message.guild.member_count`. I am not sure about channels and messages.