# Count messages from a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I would like to clean all my channels and and I'm getting there.
The problem is, it's very, very long ...

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(c => {
                if (c.isText()) {
                    let CompteurMessage = 0;
                    let CompteurSuppression;
                    c.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
                        messages.forEach(msg => {
                            msg.delete();
                        });
                    });

                    c.send(`Your server is the best, ${message.author}.`);
                }
            });
```

Do you have any idea how to go much faster, for example counting the number of messages in a channel ?

EDIT :
Now, I clone the channels but they change places ...

```
c.clone().then((clone) => {
                        clone.send(`Love ${message.author}.`);
                        const originalPosition = c.position;

                        c.delete();
                        clone.setPosition(originalPosition);
                    });
```

Channels n°3 and 4 change their place.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214425/how-to-get-how-many-messages-has-been-sent-in-a-channel

Comment: Maybe count them on the server side and query your server for the count?

Comment: You're being ratelimited, repeated mass API calls is API Abuse and will result in your client being suspended from using the Discord API

Comment: You may eventually hit messages that are 14 days or older, these messages are not deletable by the API.

Comment: Why not delete the channel, and recreate it with the same name, topic, and permissionOverwrites. This would yield the same result with way, way less calls to the API.

Comment: Yes I just did and it's good, but the channels change places even after a setPosition ... look up.

Comment: How much do they change places by?

Comment: Also, you may need await. setPosition is a promise, and if you are doing anything else to it, without await, it will take the new channel you created from before you did anything, and do whatever you chose to it. The result is that only the last thing you do to it will be cloned.

Comment: Just from one place. Channel 3 and 4 exchange them. However, the positions received from the original channels are the correct ones.

Comment: Oh no, they're all completely mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this.

## Cloning

You can clone the TextChannel using [TextChannel.clone](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=clone).
This stops you having the 14 day limitation using BulkDelete.

```js
const newChannel = await message.channel.clone();
message.channel.delete();

newChannel.send('The channel has been purged.');
```

## BulkDelete

You can delete all the messages in the last 14 days very easily.

```js
await message.channel.messages.fetch();
const messageCount = message.channel.messages.cache.map(x => x).length;
message.channel.bulkDelete(messageCount, true);
```

Note: Not the most elegant solutions since it's late at night but this should help you out.